# What's isset($_POST[''])?_POST['']:false

Tags: php, ternary-operator

What does `isset($_POST['usrnm'])?$_POST['usrnm']:false;` actually do? is it better than`isset($_POST['usrnm']) {}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ternary operator. This translates to:

```
if (isset($_POST['usrnm']))
  $userName = $_POST['usrnm']
else
  $userName = false;
```

The above code or the below one:

```
isset($_POST['usrnm'])?$_POST['usrnm']:false;
```

1. Checks if the `$_POST['usrnm']` variable has been set (can be set by a form through `POST`).
2. If it is set, the `$userName` value will be set. Else, it is set to `false`.

**Second Question**

```
isset($_POST['usrnm']) {}
```

The above code looks like a Syntax Error.

Comment: If I have the ternary operator set in all my POST data, will the code stop continuing if any of the POST data returns false?

Comment: No not like that. Depending on the situation it returns the value.

Comment: So how can I do  `isset($_POST['usrnm'])?$_POST['usrnm']:false;` and then do something like if true proceed ?

Comment: Instead of `$_POST['usrnm']` give `true`. And in front of the `isset`, add a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

**What does `isset($_POST['usrnm'])?$_POST['usrnm']:false;` actually do?**

The `?:` is ternary operator.

```
$userName = isset($_POST['usrnm']) ? $_POST['usrnm'] : false; // you must have some variable to assign the value
```

Check if `usrnm` value is present in `$_POST` array. If not it returns `false`. If value is present then it return the value of `usrnm`.

Equivalent `if..else`:

```
if (isset($_POST['usrnm'])) {
    $userName = $_POST['usrnm'];
} else {
    $userName = false;
}
```

**is it better than `isset($_POST['usrnm']) {}` ?**

It just saves some typing. Both are same.

[Blog](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Comment: If I have this in all my POST data will the code stop if any of the POST data returns false?